# Ubuntu 11.04 PHP MongoDB installation - mongo.so in php.ini but no effects

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu

I spend some time on seting up mongodb and Im confused.
To file: `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`  I added:
`exptension=mongo.so`
also tried with
`exptension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mongo.so`

Restarted apache few times but no effects :(

Its a fresh install of ubuntu 11.04 
Do you have some idea why its dead?

Answer (score 1):

`exptension=mongo.so` AND `exptension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mongo.so` are incorrect!

Use "`extension=`" word instead.

Inspect your apache `error.log` file for some module-related errors.

You should use PHP `phpinfo()` function to determine wheter your module successfully loads. 
Also check whether your file /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mongo.so exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can have syntax error in php.ini file. If you have included mongo.so after the error it will not be included